# cmake CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH not setup properly cmake version 3.7.2

Tags: cmake

on my Debian system, messaging CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH give:

```
/usr/lib/w32api;/usr/X11R6/lib;/usr/lib/X11;/usr/pkg/lib;/opt/csw/lib;/opt/lib;/usr/openwin/lib
```

Which does not look like than what you would expect from a debian system.
How do I do to have this value correctly set? is it a known bug? This lead to the fact that any search_library call fail miserably, since the path does not contain usr/lib usr/local/lib...

```
uname -a
Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed cmake by package and thus I am suprised that I am the only one to complain about that. Maybe somehow cmake is tricked into thinking my system is not a debian. What should I do? (I know I can setup manually the CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH but it kinda defeat the purpose of using a cross compilation tool.

EDIT: Well it dont even work by setting CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH (but I cannot find a lot of example, maybe I use it badly), here is the cmakelist used and the output.

```
# here you see my attempts to correct the problem in a dirty way on my platform.
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/local/lib" "/usr/lib" "/lib" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so")

find_library (libstdbuf NAMES libstdbuf stdbuf libstdbuf.so)
if(NOT libstdbuf)
  message(WARNING "libstdbuf library not found in ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH}\nDid you install coreutils?. This mean that the timing attack wont be as precise as it could. ")
  set (libstdbuf NULL)
else()
  message ("lbstbuf detected at ${libstdbuf}")
endif()
```

Output:

```
CMake Warning at .cmakedependencies_set_up:5 (message):
  libstdbuf library not found in
  /usr/lib/w32api;/usr/X11R6/lib;/usr/lib/X11;/usr/pkg/lib;/opt/csw/lib;/opt/lib;/usr/openwin/lib


  Did you install coreutils?.  This mean that the timing attack wont be as
  precise as it could.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (include)
```

EDIT3: Apparently setting directly CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH work, I thought it would search in subdirectory but you have to list them (which sucks). So now the dirty fix is the following:

```
# List subdir
MACRO(SUBDIRLIST result curdir)
  FILE(GLOB_RECURSE children LIST_DIRECTORIES true ${curdir}/* )

  SET(dirlist "")
  FOREACH(child ${children})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${child})
      LIST(APPEND dirlist ${child})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()

  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
ENDMACRO()

SUBDIRLIST (libpath1 /usr/local/lib)
SUBDIRLIST(libpath2 /usr/lib)
SUBDIRLIST(libpath3 /lib)

list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${libpath1})
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${libpath2})
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${libpath3})

find_library (libstdbuf NAMES libstdbuf stdbuf libstdbuf.so)
```

I really dont understand Cmake. Why when you specifie that the libs are in /lib, it does not look in subdirectories? If this does not work, I imagine that  even if the CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH is set properly to something like /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib /lib, it still wont work cause cmake wont explore the subdirectories. I am sure there is an explanation and I dont use find_library correctly. It should be a function that look for libraries in the standard place they should be in the used system. An other fight against Cmake.

Does someone master Cmake enought to tell me how it is suposed to work?

Comment: Can you include the CMakeLists.txt you're using?

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` variable should work. Please, show **exact path** to the file you expect to find. (Is it `/usr/local/lib/libstdbuf.so`?)

Comment: On my system this is located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so. I did not understand how find_library worked as my new edit explain. I am still lost tho

Comment: As you already found, `find_library` doesn't perform *recursive* search. The directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is standard one, and `find_library` searches there. The directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils` is not the standard, and `find_library` doesn't search there (until explicitly requested). It is important to limit a library search, otherwise it could pick a wrong library which suddenly has the same name. BTW. non-standard location of the library usually means that the library is **not intended** for being used in custom applications. However, I'm not aware about `stdbuf`.

Comment: Hey Tsyvarev, do you know how to retrieve the value where find_library search by default? Because I post this since I tought it was the CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH variable. Howewer printing it does not show any Debian standard lib. (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ for instance).

Comment: "wrong library which suddenly has the same name". Well I have not sot so much experience with the topic but is't it unlikely?. If something end up in /lib or /usr/blib... ,  it come for a project where people checked for name collision of their library name gainst other projects allready. If you add stuff yourself manually in the systems lib folders, you are probably doing it wrong in my opinion.